# remove a a class and then hide it with jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, delay, show, addclass

the following code i have does not seem to work.

```
$("ul li a").live("click", function() {
        $(".myMegaMenuDiv").addClass('hideit').delay(300).removeClass('hideit');
 });
```

I have a mega menu, so when you hover over a menu item it shows a div ".myMegaMenuDiv". But when I click a link in that div, i want it do disapear, as it currently does not. I was hoping the above code would resolve this.

"hideit" adds a value of "display:none"

It works when I just have "addClass", but when I add "delay" and "removeClass" it stops working.

EDIT: Also... after I hide the ".myMegaMenuDiv" the menu does not show when I hover over a nav menu item, so it kind of needs to remove the class too

Comment: do you want to hide it and then show it again after 300 ms?

Comment: `.delay` is used to delay jQuery animation.. it doesn't work with functions like `addClass` or `removeClass`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to hide the div on click, you can just use the `hide` function. Also, the `live` function is deprecated, so it's best to use `on`.

```
$("ul li a").on("click", function() {
    $(".myMegaMenuDiv").hide();
});
```

If you want to hide and show, you can use a setTimeout:

```
$("ul li a").on("click", function() {
    $(".myMegaMenuDiv").hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".myMegaMenuDiv").show();
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: just edited my post to show he issue of only hiding, thanks for reply

Comment: @AnthW Great! Glad to help! Since this answer helped you out, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Comment: I tried soon after but I had to wait 5 mins. done now, thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

The `.hide()` and `.show()` methods [can receive a number to determine their duration](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), therefore you could try this instead:

```
$(".myMegaMenuDiv").hide(300).show(0);
```

If you want no animation, you could do it like this as well:

```
$('.myMegaMenuDiv').hide(0).delay(300).show(0)
```

Comment: This actually animates it, I don't think it's what he wants. And the show does not seem to work because of the duration. It would have to be in the callback.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I got it working from the above comment, recommending setTimeout

Comment: Your first example does not work as stated in my comment above.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Good point! I corrected it and also included a better answer, thanks for your feedback...

Comment: Yeah seems like the best answer to me now. Although I remember that I had some problems a while ago with duration 0. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`delay` isn't just a simple pause timer. it only applies to items in the animation queue. You need to use `setTimeout`

http://api.jquery.com/delay/